# How to prove a set is compact and path connected under a function

Tags: general-topology, compactness, path-connected

I am having the following question

1. Let $\mathbb{R}^4$ be equipped with the standard topology induced by the Euclidean metric and let $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by
   $$
   f\left(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\right)=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-x_4^2
   $$
   Put $A=f^{-1}(\{1\}), B=A \cap\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^4: x_4=0\right\}, C=f^{-1}([0, \infty))$.
   Prove whether the following statements are true or false.

With the help of comments, I have the following attempt, please correct me if anything is wrong through my learning process, thanks again.

$A$ is not compact. A subset of $R^n$ is compact iff it is bounded and closed. $A$ is clearly not bounded as there exist no $r>0$ such that $d(a,b)<r$  for all $a,b$ in A, therefore A is not bounded and not compact.

$B$ is compact, as there is a constrain on $x_4$, $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$ which is bounded by $r=2\pi$, therefore $B$ is bounded. Also, $R^4-B$ is open as it can be covered by open balls so $B$ is closed. Hence, $B$ is compact

Comment: So according to your understanding, $[0, 1]\subset \Bbb{R}$ is not compact as $\Bbb{R}$ is not compact

Comment: The subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is bounded and closed. $A$ is not bounded. $B$ is bounded and closed.

Comment: thank you, I misused the theory saying a subset is compact to proof a subset is not compact

Comment: About c,d, you have to work more and include your attempts in your post, or better in a new distinct post, as commented by @5xum . Beware to not misinterpret the definition of path-connectedness. It is not $\exists f\forall x,y$ but $\forall x,y\exists f$ (i.e. $f$ depends on $x,y$... of course since they are its values at endpoints). Also, wlog $[a,b]=[0,1].$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that A B are both not compact because a set is compact if and only if it is closed and it is a subset of a compact topological space X. But in this case $R^4$ is not a compact space under Euclidean metric.

This is very wrong. By this same logic, you could also prove that $[0,1]$ is not compact, because it is a subset of $\mathbb R$ which is not compact. What's more, your logic actually implies that **no compact subsets of $\mathbb R^4$ exist**, which is absurd (since finite sets are always compact).

In fact, the property is "$A$ is compact if and only if it is a closed subspace of **some** compact space $X$", and this property cannot really be used to prove that a set is not compact. This is because the only way you could do that is to prove that everytime $A$ is a subspace of $X$, then either $A$ is not closed or $X$ is not compact, and that is equally hard to prove (since you would also have to cover the case when $X=A$, in which case $A$ is clearly closed, so you basically need to prove $A$ is not compact, to prove that $A$ is not compact.

Comment: (+1) You did not answer the questions abcd but I think what you wrote is much more useful. However, would you mind completing it please, so that it becomes a *stricto sensu* answer? (May be for cd, also correct a potential misunderstanding "$\exists f,\forall x,y\dots$")

Comment: @AnneBauval Providing complete solution is a bad practice and should not be encouraged.

Comment: It really depends on the question. But in this answer we have the extreme opposite, which is not good as well.

Comment: Actually, I did not answer parts c and d for two reasons. One, posts here should be one question, one post, not four questions one post. Two, if I look at the second part, then the post is an example of a "solve my problem for me" post which I don't think should be encouraged.

Comment: yes, please provide some tips on how to proof abcd, much appreciated

Comment: Thank you 5xum for your detailed comment. Now I completely agree with you.

Comment: @RuoLinWang Did you trying picturing it in your head?. For example what would $B$ look like?. Just try to think for what $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})$ would you be satisfying $x_{4}=0$ and hence $x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2}=1$ . Does it remind you of anything?.

Comment: @RuoLinWang You already got sufficient (compared to the efforts) "tips on how to prove" ab, in HeroZhang001's comment (below your post). As for cd, I just commented (also below your post).

Comment: thank you @AnneBauval. Your comments are helpful, will close the question now.